# How to know installation action in installshield merge module type project?

Tags: installshield, installscript, merge-module

I am using installshield to build a setup project. I have one InstallScript type project in which I have multiple merge module project included. In each merge module I have some custom install script logic. I noticed that this install script logic is running every time (install/uninstall/repair). I want to control these based of the action install/uninstall/repair. Is there any environment variable or flag from where I can get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean an InstallScript project that uses multiple merge modules via the Merge Module Holder Object, no there's no great way. This is part of why the MMHO has been deprecated. Each of the merge modules is built into its own .msi and launched from the InstallScript project; you should probably do that manually so you can pass properties to each .msi file.

However since these are .msi files, you might check to see if the standard conditions like the ones in this article can help. http://www.installshield.com/news/newsletter/0212-articles/msiconditions.asp Note that these would have to be in the merge modules.